# Defining De Morgan dual using $\neg: \mathbf{A}^{\text{op}} \to \mathbf{A}$

Tags: boolean-algebra, dual-maps

**Preamble.** Suppose $\textbf{A} = \langle A,\bot,\top,\vee,\wedge,\neg\rangle$ is a Boolean algebra. The "opposite" Boolean algebra $\textbf{A}^\text{op} = \langle A,\top,\bot,\wedge,\vee,\neg\rangle$ has the same carrier $A$ but transposes the operations, so that $\top_{\textbf{A}^\text{op}} = \bot_{\textbf{A}}$, etc. We can also adapt the standard definition of *opposite functor* to monotone maps between Boolean algebras: for any $f: \textbf{A} \to \textbf{B}$, define $f^\text{op}: \textbf{A}^\text{op} \to \textbf{B}^\text{op}$ to simply be $f$, understood as a function of type $A \to B$ between the carriers. This definition is "well-typed" because $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{A}^\text{op}$ have the same carrier.

$^\text{op}$ allows us to think of negation in two ways. First, as an order-inverting isomorphism $\neg: \textbf{A} \to \textbf{A}$  which takes $a \in A$ to its negation $\neg a \in A$. Second (for example [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0931)), as an order-preserving isomorphism of type $\textbf{A}^\text{op} \to \textbf{A}$ (or $\textbf{A} \to \textbf{A}^\text{op}$) which takes $a \in A$ to itself. In this latter case $a \in \textbf{A}$ represents its own complement in $\textbf{A}^\text{op}$ and vice versa.

**Problem.** Now, for any function $g: \textbf{A} \to \textbf{B}$ between Boolean algebras, we can define its De Morgan dual:

> $g^\circ: \textbf{A} \to \textbf{B} := \neg_{\textbf{B}} \circ g \circ \neg_{\textbf{A}}$

Here we mean $\neg_{\textbf{A}}$ and $\neg_{\textbf{B}}$ in the order-inverting ($\textbf{A} \to \textbf{A}$) sense rather than the order-preserving $(\textbf{A}^\text{op} \to \textbf{A})$ sense. However, I often prefer the $\textbf{A}^\text{op} \to \textbf{A}$ interpretation, and was expecting to be able to use it to define the De Morgan dual in the following way (writing $\dagger$ rather than $^\circ$ to distinguish the definitions):

> $g^\dagger: \textbf{A} \to \textbf{B} := \neg_{\textbf{B}} \circ g^\text{op} \circ \neg_{\textbf{A}^\text{op}}$

Here we mean $\neg_{\textbf{B}}$ in the order-preserving ($\textbf{B} \to \textbf{B}^\text{op}$) sense where it acts as the identity on the carrier $B$. Similarly $\neg_{\textbf{A}^\text{op}}$ is the identity function on $A$ interpreted at the type $\textbf{A} \to \textbf{A}^\text{op}$.

However (and perhaps this is obvious), $\dagger$ doesn't seem to yield the same operation as $^\circ$. Indeed, $g^\dagger$ is simply another way of expressing $g$.

Consider for example the (constant) monotonic function $f: \textbf{2} \to \textbf{2}$ which maps its argument to $\text{tt}$. Here $\text{2}$ denotes the set $\{\text{ff}, \text{tt}\}$ and $\textbf{2} = \langle \text{2}, \bot, \top, \vee, \wedge, \neg\rangle$ denotes the Boolean algebra where $\bot = \text{tt}$ and $\top = \text{tt}$ and $\neg$, $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are defined in the usual way. It is easy to see that $f^\circ \neq f^{\dagger}$. Writing the type of $\text{tt}$ or $\text{ff}$ as a subscript, but omitting the subscripts on $\neg$, we have:

> $f^\circ(\text{ff}_{\textbf{2}}) = \neg f(\neg \text{ff}_{\textbf{2}}) = \neg f(\text{tt}_{\textbf{2}}) = \neg\text{tt}_{\textbf{2}} = \text{ff}_{\textbf{2}}$

On the other hand:

> $f^\dagger(\text{ff}_{\textbf{2}}) = \neg f^\text{op}(\neg\text{ff}_{\textbf{2}}) = \neg f^\text{op}(\text{ff}_{\textbf{2}^\text{op}}) = \neg f(\text{ff}_{\textbf{2}}) = \neg\text{tt}_{\textbf{2}} = \neg\text{tt}_{\textbf{2}^\text{op}} = \text{tt}_{\textbf{2}}$

Maybe I'm misunderstanding $f^\text{op}$. The steps above contain some suspect implicit coercions: on the way into $f^\text{op}$ we coerce $\text{ff}$ from $\textbf{2}^\text{op}$ to $\textbf{2}$ so we can pass it to $f$, and on the way out of $f^\text{op}$ we coerce the $\text{tt}$ returned by $f$ from $\textbf{2}$ to $\textbf{2}^\text{op}$. These are well-typed because $\textbf{2}^\text{op}$ and $\textbf{2}$ have the same carrier, and they make everything fit together "correctly", but not in a way that yields the De Morgan dual. Indeed, given that the identity map from $\textbf{2}^\text{op} \to \textbf{2}$ is effectively negation, we might note that $f^\text{op}$ already resembles a De Morgan dual, but at the type $\textbf{A}^\text{op} \to \textbf{B}^\text{op}$ rather than $\textbf{A} \to \textbf{B}$.

Is there a way to define the De Morgan dual of $f$ at the type $\textbf{A} \to \textbf{B}$ using negations of the form $\neg_{\textbf{A}}: \textbf{A}^\text{op} \to \textbf{A}$ and the (appropriately defined) opposite of $f$? Any corrections to my analysis above would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm new to math.stackexchange -- if someone could help with formatting the title that would be great!

Comment: Fixed title formatting

Answer (score 2):

$g^{op}$, viewed as a plain set-theoretic function from a set $A$ to a set $B$, is the same function as $g$. Similarly, $\neg_{\mathbf{A}^{op}}$ is the same function as $\neg_{\mathbf{A}}$. So $g^{\circ}$ and $g^{\dagger}$ are the same function.

Your confusion arises from the notation $\mathrm{ff}_{\mathbf{2}}$ and $\mathrm{ff}_{\mathbf{2}^{op}}$, which does not make much sense. The universe of the two algebras $\mathbf{2}$ and $\mathbf{2}^{op}$ is the same, namely $\{ \mathrm{ff}, \mathrm{tt} \}$. There is no $\mathrm{ff}_{\mathbf{2}}$ versus $\mathrm{ff}_{\mathbf{2}^{op}}$.

What does make sense is distinguishing the interpretation of the constant symbol $\bot$ in $\mathbf{2}$, which is $\mathrm{ff}$, from the interpretation of the constant symbol $\bot$ in $\mathbf{2}^{op}$, which is $\mathrm{tt}$. So one can write something like $\bot_{\mathbf{2}} = \top_{\mathbf{2}^{op}}$, but $\neg \mathrm{ff}_{\mathbf{2}} = \mathrm{ff}_{\mathbf{2}^{op}}$ is confused.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. $¬\text{ff}_2 = \text{ff}_{2^{\text{op}}}$ refers to the action of $id_{\{\text{tt},\text{ff}\}}$ interpreted as $\neg: 2 \to 2^{\text{op}}$.

Comment: @Roly Well, then of course the two functions will be different, as you correctly observed. The question is then, why do you want to use the notation $\neg_{\mathbf{2}^{op}}$ to denote the identity function, rather than either the order-inverting map $\mathbf{2}^{op} \to \mathbf{2}^{op}$ or the order-preserving map $\mathbf{2} \to \mathbf{2}^{op}$?

Comment: Suppose $\neg_{A}$ by convention denotes a "covariant" endofunctor (on a poset category) of type $A^{\text{op}} \to A$. By the same convention (and the involutivity of $^\text{op}$), $\neg_{A^{\text{op}}}$ will denote a "covariant" endofunctor of type $A \to A^{\text{op}}$. I believe this is a fairly common convention. In this instance, the "implementation" of such a functor (= monotone function) is given by the identity function on the carrier set that (as you identified) is shared by $A$ and $A^{\text{op}}$.

Comment: @Roly But the identity map (which is what you said you want to interpret $\neg_{\mathbf{A}}$ as) is not covariant as a map $\mathbf{A}^{op} \to \mathbf{A}$. The negation is the natural covariant map $\mathbf{A}^{op} \to \mathbf{A}$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "contravariant" in both cases in my previous comment. My bad. I'm out of my 5 mins editing time so I can't fix it.

Comment: @Roly Well, then I don't know how help you further. My interpretation is that you wrote down two clearly different definitions, one using the negation and one using the identity map (which your notation obscures by strangely using $\neg$ to denote the identity map), and now you are puzzled that they are indeed different. Hopefully someone else will be able to write an answer which gets to the bottom of your perplexion.

Comment: I deleted my last couple of comments, which persisted with my misunderstanding. You are of course correct in your comment above (the identity map is not covariant as a map $A^{\text{op}} \to $; the negation is the natural covariant map $A^{\text{op}} \to A$.) If you would like to upgrade this to an answer (or modify your existing answer accordingly), I will accept it. Thanks again.